# Unable to Set Cookie in Node JS - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies

I am using Node JS on serverside and React on client side. On successful auth when i try to use res.cookie and set a cookie. On client side however the Cookie only shows up in Network tab and does not get set in application tab. I am using  axios for making the request and have even set the credentials header to include since I am using cors. Here is my code below

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  loginService.login(email, password, (userPublicData, token, err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401);
      res.send({ user: null, error: err });
    } else {
      res.status(200);
      res.cookie("jwt", token);
      res.send({ user: userPublicData, error: err });
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my client side function

```
async function authenticateUser() {
    console.log(values);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["credentials"] = "include";
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", values)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(dataJson => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userData", dataJson);
        props.history.push("/admin");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("Auth error", err);
      });
  }
```

The cookie appears in network tab but doesnot get set in the application cookies. Some help would be much appreciated

Comment: I ran into a ton of problems with this too. In the end I found it was my cors settings on the server level. I'm using express & needed to include the `origin` option. Without it I'd never see the cookie returned to the client.